# Meteor's Iron:router: how to render template based on Session variable (cordovaReady)?

Tags: cordova, meteor, iron-router

I'm using Iron:router + Cordova in my Meteor project.

Since my app depends on Cordova libraries, I need to wait for Cordova to be ready.

**client/lib/init.js**

```
Session.set('cordovaReady', false);
var initCordova = function() {

    /*
     * init filetransfer cordova plugin
     */
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(),
        storageDataDirectory = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

    // make them global
    window.fileTransfer = fileTransfer;
    window.storageDataDirectory = storageDataDirectory;

    Session.set('cordovaReady', true);

};
initCordova();
```

**shared/lib/routing.js**:

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    layoutTemplate: 'common' 
});

Router.route('/config', {
    name:'config',
    template:'configuration',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
    // TODO: allow template rendering only once cordovaReady session variable is == true

    this.layout(null);
    this.render("configuration");
 }
})
```

**client/app.js**

```
Router.go('config');
```

**How can I wait until cordovaReady == true, then route to /config**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do:

```
onBeforeAction: function(){
  if ( Session.get('cordovaReady') ) this.next();
  else this.render('loading');
});
```

Assuming you have a loading template (ex: a spinner) named `loading`.